# Will SSIS 2012 work with SQL Server 2008R2 (not integrated)

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, ssis

Our company has SQL Server 2008R2 and plans to upgrade to 2012 in late 2013 or early 2014. I would like to use SSIS 2012 now as we do have the software.

We have a company policy where we cannot run SSIS packages on the database server itself. We run them from another app server, **not** integrated services.

**My question is**, if I were to install all 2012 composent for SSIS on our app server would there be any potental issues? I have not used SSIS 2012 yet so I do not know if the OLE DB compoents Id use to point to our SQL 2008 instance would be an issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There will be no issues as SSIS 2012 will work with previous versions of SQL Server. I recently upgraded from 2008R2 to 2012 with 45 SSIS packages and all are working fine. As Always Test all your packages before hand on 2012.

from [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-integration-services/bg-p/SSIS) link :

*As you may already know, the SQL Native Client OLE DB provider is being deprecated. This doesn't affect other OLE DB providers or the OLE DB API. Also, **the SSIS OLE DB components are not being deprecated.**
In SQL Server 2012 SSIS, you can continue to use OLE DB connections and will need to for components such as the Lookup transformation and the Slowly Changing Dimension transformation that require OLE DB. In the post-Denali release, you’ll be able to upgrade and continue to operate these packages without needing to do additional work to explicitly remove OLE DB from the packages.*

Comment: Hey Kin, thanks for the response. I am assuming this is only valid if you are not use integrated services? Did you only upgrade SSIS 2012 or also your database to 2012?

Comment: Yes we upgraded to 2012 along with our databases. But the SSIS packages reference to some old 2008R2 servers as well.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL Server Upgrade Advisor (on the install media as well as in the [SQL Server Feature Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=29065)) may be able to analyse Integration Services packages to identify whether your packages use any features that are going to be deprecated.

The list of [discontinued SSIS 2012 features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500429.aspx) is quite small. Unless you're running packages that use ActiveX Scripts or were built in the SQL Server 2000 DTS era, you're unlikely to run into any insurmountable issues. We've had a similar experience to @Kin, migrating dozens of packages from 2008R2 to 2012 without any problems.

Comment: The good thing about our team (or bad i guess) is that we will be rebuilding our 2000 DTS pacages directly to 2012. So, no conversion. I was able to install all the 2012 tools and everything looks good. The only thing to note is that the Oracle Attunity component available free from MS did not convert in a few 2008 packages, easy to rebuild though.